# Is there an equivalent of 'onomatopoeia' for words inspired by the appearance of thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

'Onomatopoeia' is a reasonably common word used to describe words that sound like the sounds they're used to describe. I was wondering whether there was an analogous term for words that sound like what their meanings *look* like — words like 'glint' or 'shimmer'.

Comment: Synaesthesia ...?

Comment: Granted, the [Bouba/kiki effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect) is real, but I suggest most of the time we're just dealing with the fact that we *know* the meanings of the words we actually use, and *that's* why we tend to extrapolate meaning inherent in the form of the symbols themselves.

Comment: @FumbleFingers whether we're extrapolating meaning after the fact or not, there could still be a word for the concept I've described.

Comment: @user867: Indeed. There are words for all sorts of concepts that don't necessarily reflect the real world, and oftentimes the existence of a word indicates that at least some people do (or did) believe the referent to be "real" (*astrology*, the *hereafter*, for example). I'm not saying there are no words for your concept (deadly's *sound symbolism* seems as good as any to me) - just that for most practical purposes it's a concept born out of fanciful thinking rather than observable linguistic fact.

Comment: Wouldn't the equivalent concept to onomatopoeia be words that *look* like their meanings? Not that I can think of any at the moment...

Comment: @Marthaª Four comes to mind. So does Mog, especially when written vertically. Word, letters and text all work, though I feel a little like LINES is cheating.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not sure I understand the point you're making. Even if the word doesn't reflect anything that truly exists, surely there could still be value in knowing it. I know I've gotten good mileage out of 'Griffin.'

Comment: @user867: My point is that whilst there might be *something* to the idea of "sound symbolism", I think for most purposes it should be taken with a generous pinch of salt. In the real world, it doesn't exist anywhere near as much as some people might think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An [ideophone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideophone) — a word that sounds like its idea or concept.

It's quite a general term that could include onomatopoeia. There are other terms for certain types of [sound symbolism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism).

Answer (score 3):

John Lawler has [some works](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/#mono) on phonosemantics, which connect the meaning of words to the way they sound. I think that Bouba/Kiki, onomatopoeia and the OP's question can be seen as special cases of phonosemantics.

Perhaps @JohnLawler himself can drop by and explain much better than me. :-)